# show a function is Borel measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove the continuous function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable in the following two steps:

First let $G = \{U \subset \mathbb{R} \vert g^{-1}(U) \text{is Borel} \}$

(a) show all open sets are in $G$.

(b) show $G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

So for (a) at least, take an arbitrary open set in $\mathbb{R}$ call it $V$, then $V$ can be written as a countable union of standard basis elements, that is,

$V = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty (a_j,b_j)$ where $a_j \leq b_j$ are real numbers. Then by continuity of $g$, we have that the pullback $g^{-1}(V)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}{^n}$. Then this pullback is the union of open balls in $n$ dimension. How do I show something is a Borel set? I know my set can be generated by open sets and I know Borel sets are elements of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra which is sort of like a topological space (in that it has an axiomatic definition of certain closures of its elements) except that now the entire space need be in the collection of subsets, together with countable unions and intersections, and complements. Where do I go from here? So for (b) and I supposed to show these axioms hold for members of $G$?

Comment: You don't need to decompose $V$. It's just that $g^{-1}(V)$ is open by continuity, and in particular a Borel set. For part $(b)$ yes, you need to check that $G$ satisfies the axioms of a sigma algebra. For example, $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R^n}$, which is a Borel set. So $\mathbb{R}\in G$. Similarly, check the other axioms, they are all easy.

Comment: So for example, suppose $U_1,U_2,... \in G$ and show their union and intersection is in $G$ and if $U \in G$ then $G \backslash U$ is in $G$ as well?

Comment: I believe you mean $\mathbb{R}\setminus U$, not $G\setminus U$. Other than that, yes, this is what you have to prove.

Comment: oh my gosh yes the reals set minus the element of $G$ not $G$ lol thanks!

Comment: question for closed under intersection and union, what do I use? say $U_1,U_2,... \in G$. then for $j=1,2,...$ we have that $U_j \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $g^{-1}(U_j)$ is Borel. Then clearly the intersection and union are subsets of the reals but then how do you show the pullbacks $g^{-1}(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty U_j), g^{-1}(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty U_j)$ are Borel sets. I guess I am still missing what it means to be Borel, like what criteria must you satisfy? Does it just mean they are either countable union or intersection of all closed subsets or all closed subsets?

Comment: for complement do I use the fact that complements of open are closed?

Comment: Inverse image under a function *distributes* over $\bigcup$ and $\bigcap$. That is, $g^{-1}(\bigcup_n U_n) = \bigcup_n g^{-1}(U_n)$. It's enough to show this, and show also that inverse image also distributes over complement. But these are true of every function, and every indexed collection! They're just general facts of set theory.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please,  upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: @BrianO oh my gosh cannot believe I missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks to prove the continuous function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable in the following two steps:

First let $G = \{U \subset \mathbb{R} \:\vert\: g^{-1}(U) \text{ is Borel } \}$

(a) show all open sets are in $G$.

(b) show $G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

**Proof**: Let us prove (a).
Since $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, we have that, for all $A$ open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $g^{-1}(A)$ is an open subset  of $\mathbb{R}$. So, in particular  $g^{-1}(A)$ is Borel. In other words, all open sets are in $G$.

Let us prove (b).

(b.1) Since $g^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$  and $\emptyset$ is Borel, we have that $g^{-1}(\emptyset)$ is Borel. So $\emptyset \in G$.

(b.2) Suppose that $E \in G$. Then $g^{-1}(E)$ is Borel. So $g^{-1}(E)^c$ is Borel. Since
$$ g^{-1}(E^c)= g^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus E) = g^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \setminus g^{-1}(E)= \mathbb{R}^n \setminus g^{-1}(E) = g^{-1}(E)^c$$
we have that $g^{-1}(E^c)$ is Borel. So, $E^c \in G$.

(b.3) Let $\{E_j\}_j$ be a sequence of sets in $G$. Then, for all $j$, $g^{-1}(E_j)$ is Borel. So $\bigcup_j g^{-1} (  E_j  )  $ is Borel. Since
$$ g^{-1} \left ( \bigcup_j E_j  \right)= \bigcup_j g^{-1} (  E_j  )  $$
we have that $g^{-1} \left ( \bigcup_j E_j  \right)$ is Borel. So $ \bigcup_j E_j  \in G$.

So $G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I thought sigma algebras are closed under intersection, union, and complement. I thought only the whole space needs to be an element not the empty set? OR are different text books different on how they define it?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame , Since a $\sigma$-algebra is closed by complement, the whole space is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra **if and only if** the empty set is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame , Since a $\sigma$-algebra is closed by complement, it is closed under countable  intersections **if and only if** it is closed under countable unions.

Comment: AHH you're right can't believe I missed that!